# Как мне сделать прозрачным только фон?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

я испольлзую бутстрап, и как сделать у навбара прозрачным только фон?
[image: Как сейчас у меня]

И самая проблема в том что я не могу понять как сделать прозрачным только фон?
именно у навбара

Код

```
<nav style="opacity: 0.7; margin: 15px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #ffff;" class="navbar fixed-top bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a style="opacity: 1;" class="navbar-brand text-light" href="#">
      <img src="assets/favicon.ico" alt="Iri logo" width="30" class="d-inline-block align-text-top">
      Ири
    </a>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Ну так и сделайте прозрачным только фон: `background: rgba(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.bg-dark {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) !important
}
```